# Кеширование в nginx

Tags: nginx, cookie

В моем проекте кеширование в nginx выполняется по некоторому ключу cache_key, который формируется на бэкенде и хранится у пользователя в cookies.

В рамках более тонкой настройки кеширования через nginx возникла следующая задача: 
Необходимо, чтобы запрос без cache_key средствами nginx отредиректился на определенный роут бэкенда, который вычислит новый cache_key и уже с ним сделать еще один запрос к nginx(за кешем). Если по новому cache_key в nginx пусто, то делается полноценный запрос за контентом на бэкенд.

Необходимо чтобы от клиента делался только 1 запрос. Вся остальная вышеперечисленная магия выполнялась только внутри nginx. Как правильно написать nginx-конфиг для такой реализации?

Пример существующего конфига:

```
proxy_cache_key "$request_method|$host|$request_uri|$cookie_cache_key";
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

location / {
    if ($http_cookie !~* "cache_key.{32}") {
        set $nocache_flag "ok";
    }
    add_header "X-Cache" $upstream_cache_status;
    proxy_cache_bypass $nocache_flag;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass 'http://127.0.0.1:8181';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалось реализовать через X-Accel-Redirect. Cookies, полученные от бэкенда автоматически подставляются во второй запрос.

```
location / {
    if ($http_cookie !~* "cache_key.{32}") {
        error_page 477 = @cacherefresh;
    }
    add_header "X-Cache" $upstream_cache_status;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass 'http://127.0.0.1:4000';
}

location @cacherefresh {
    rewrite ^ /cacherefresh?path=$1 last;
    proxy_pass 'http://127.0.0.1:4000';
}
```

Директива error_page понадобилась чтобы использовать именованный location и избежать зацикливания.
В X-Accel-Redirect подставляется оригинальный путь, который был получен от клиента и через директиву rewrite отправлен в качестве параметра path.

```
def cacherefresh
    response.set_cookie('cache_key', value: 'some_value')
    response.headers['X-Accel-Redirect'] = params[:path]
    return
end
```

Таким образом необходимость в директиве proxy_cache_bypass отпадает автоматически, так как не может быть ситуаций, когда отсутствует ключ кеширования.